# how to update data only once in a day?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am facing One problem. I am using Cakephp2.0 Framework. I want that **searchcount** will be updated once in a day. For example:-

**Here is my code:**

```
Starting serachcount = 0;
if it access today(26dec 2016) means n number of times its count will 
be **serachcount** = 1;

If it is not  access by tomorrow (27dec 2016) its count should not be 
 updated its still **serachcount** = 2;
And this process carries on
```

Can anyone help me here is my function

**Here is my code  what I have tried**

```
public function visits($id=null){
        $this->loadModel('User');
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $data= $this->request->data;
            $id = $data['id'];
            $userdata = $this->User->find('first',array(
                'conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$id),
                'fields'=>array('id','searchcount')
                )
            );
            $this->User->id = $id;
            $searchcount = $userdata['searchcount'];
            $searchcount = $searchcount+1;
            $this->User->saveField('searchcount',$searchcount);
            echo $searchcount; die;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add a field in your table, `ex : __count_date__` and store in it the time you updated the counter, next time you want to update, look at that field value and compare it to the current time, if it's not within the same day, update the counter. otherwise dont.

Answer (score 1):

You just need simple logic as mentioned by @Ayaou:

```
1. add field in your table eg. count_date 
2. do not forget to update count_date when searchcount get updated
3. make your visits function something like this:

if($this->request->is('post')){
 $data= $this->request->data;
 $id = $data['id'];
 $userdata = $this->User->find('first',array(
   'conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$id),
   'fields'=>array('id','searchcount','count_date')
            )
        );
  $this->User->id = $id;
  $searchcount = $userdata['searchcount'];
  $countDate = $userdata['count_date'];
  $dateToday = date('Y-m-d');
  if($countDate != $dateToday) {
     $dataToUpdate["count_date"] = $dateToday;
     $dataToUpdate["searchcount"] = $searchcount+1;
     $this->User->save($dataToUpdate);
   } else {
     // already updated today
   }
 }
```